# azure-spring-boot for springboot 2.6.3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-azure

We have recently upgraded spring boot from 2.4.3 to 2.6.3 and spring-cloud.version to "2021.0.1".
Can some one help pls here how I can find suitable **azure spring dependencies** which is compatible for spring 2.6.3 and spring-cloud.version to "2021.0.1.

Thanks
Dins Kumar

Answer (score 1):

The compatible version can be found here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Spring-Versions-Mapping. But as [@backhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18239001/backhere) mentioned, the 4.0 will be GAed in days, with many improvements and new features to make all the Spring Cloud Azure libraries more consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I have few more queries regarding azure springboot:             I am currently using spring-cloud-azure-dependencies 4.0.0 any suggestions what is the best suitable to be used for azure-security-keyvault-keys.

Comment: The spring-cloud-azure-dependencies include the azure-sdk-bom, which means the `spring-cloud-azure-dependencies` also manage the version for `azure-security-keyvault-keys`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/b8e2cc8bf4b1d89b6d9156cd94d762009c74afbf/sdk/spring/CHANGELOG.md#400-2022-03-28), the spring cloud azure 4.0 version may meet your needs.

The libraries of the 4.0 GA version are not released yet, but it's in the process and will be released in a few days.
You can check with this [link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure.spring/spring-cloud-azure-dependencies).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I have few more queries regarding azure springboot:             I am currently using spring-cloud-azure-dependencies 4.0.0 any suggestions what is the best suitable to be used for azure-security-keyvault-keys.